# error: '@snprintf' defined with type 'i32 (i8*, i32, i8*, ...)*'

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have an LLVM IR code that looks something like this:

```
declare i32 @snprintf(i8*, i32, i8*, ...)

define i32 @main () {
    ...
    %9 = load i8*, i8** %8
    %10 = load i8*, i8** %2
    %11 = load i8*, i8** %0
    %12 = load i8, i8* %11
    %13 = call i32 (i8*, i32, i8*, ...)* @snprintf(i8* %10, i32 3, i8* %9, i8 %12)
    ...
```

The last line raise this:

```
error: '@snprintf' defined with type 'i32 (i8*, i32, i8*, ...)*'
%13 = call i32 (i8*, i32, i8*, ...)* @snprintf(i8* %10, i32 3, i8* %9, i8 %12)
```

I have researched the LLVM documentation but I can't figure out what's wrong. :-(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you save your file? The error message says it is `call i32 (i8`, but your code has correct `call i32 (i8*`.

Comment: Actually the quotes hidden the '*' character for some reason. I fixed the post using code formatting. By the way, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Just removed the `*` after call type's parenthesis:

`%13 = call i32 (i8*, i32, i8*, ...) @snprintf(i8* %10, i32 3, i8* %9, i8 %12)`